# Need more efficient way to create many entities

Tags: entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I'm struggling with how to efficiently structure my LINQ queries so that I can minimize the number of round trip calls to the database.

With the current code below, each of these object creations can produce numerous open and close database connections.

How might some of this code be restructured to minimize the calls to the database, and insert more objects in single calls?

I've also resorted to calling SaveChanges multiple times, do to issues of objects not existing in the context until I save the changes.

```
public IActionResult AddSnapshots([FromBody]List<MembershipSnapshot> snapshots, bool? update = false)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid) { return new BadRequestObjectResult(ModelState); }
            if (snapshots.Count == 0)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Empty", "There were no records provided to be inserted.");
                return new BadRequestObjectResult(ModelState);
            }

            // Get the composite keys from the supplied list
            var snapshotKeys = snapshots.Select(s => new { s.MembershipYear, s.DataDate, s.Aggregate }).ToArray();
            // Find which records already exist in the database, pulling their composite keys
            var snapshotsInDb = platformContext.MembershipSnapshots.Where(s => snapshotKeys.Contains(new { s.MembershipYear, s.DataDate, s.Aggregate }))
                                               .Select(s => new { s.MembershipYear, s.DataDate, s.Aggregate }).ToArray();
            // And filter them out, so we remain with the ones that don't yet exist
            var addSnapshots = snapshots.Where(s => !snapshotsInDb.Contains(new { s.MembershipYear, s.DataDate, s.Aggregate }))
                .ToList();
            platformContext.MembershipSnapshots.AddRange(addSnapshots);
            platformContext.SaveChanges();

            // In addition to adding all of the snapshots that didn't exist, we'll populate the
            // membership categories, aggregates and aggregate collections if they don't already exist
            var aggregates = snapshots.Select(s => new { Name = s.Aggregate, Category = s.AggregateCategory }).Distinct();

            var addAggregates = aggregates.Where(a => !platformContext.MembershipAggregates.Any(ma => ma.Name == a.Name))
                                          .GroupBy(a => a.Name).Select(g => g.First())
                                          .Select(a => new Aggregate { Name = a.Name });
            platformContext.AddRange(addAggregates);
            platformContext.SaveChanges();

            var addCategories = aggregates.Where(a => !platformContext.MembershipCategories.Any(c => c.Name == a.Category))
                                          .GroupBy(a => a.Category).Select(g => g.First())
                                          .Select(a => new Category { Name = a.Category });
            platformContext.AddRange(addCategories);
            platformContext.SaveChanges();

            var addAggregateCollection = aggregates.Where(a => !platformContext.AggregateCollections.Any(ma => ma.Name == a.Name))
                                                   .GroupBy(a => a.Name).Select(g => g.First())
                                                   .Select(a => new AggregateCollection()
                                                   {
                                                       Name = a.Name,
                                                       Category = platformContext.MembershipCategories.Where(c => c.Name == a.Category).Single(),
                                                       Description = a.Name,
                                                       AggregateCollectionAggregates = new List<AggregateCollectionAggregate>()
                                                       {
                                                           new AggregateCollectionAggregate()
                                                           {
                                                               Aggregate = platformContext.MembershipAggregates.Where(ma => ma.Name == a.Name).Single()
                                                           }
                                                       }
                                                   });
            platformContext.AddRange(addAggregateCollection);
            platformContext.SaveChanges();

            return new StatusCodeResult(StatusCodes.Status200OK);
        }
```

Comment: First of all you need to call Saves changes only once at the end of the method, and you can avoid null reference by initializing the properties from model.

Comment: I'm not talking about null reference, I'm talking about no items existing in the context until I commit the changes.

Answer (score 1):

Mate, you need to thing at `DbContext` like to a **waiter** in a restaurant.

If you are with 10 friends in a restaurant, the waiter **is not** coming taking the order of the first friend, then **going** to the kitchen to give the info to the man cook, then is **coming** back for the second friend **go again** till kitchen ...
(if is doing like that, please go to another restaurant).

***The waiter is coming to your table and get all info he needs and then is going to the man cook,*** same with DbContext, you can add as many new objects as you want, it will know about each new object, and will not complain as long as you initialize the objects.

Like with the waiter, if is a good waiter will know what wine do they have and what he can give you, if you ask for some other wine he can tell you from start "No we do not have" because he is a good waiter and always know what he have or not.
In order for your `Dbcontext` to be good `Dbcontext`, you need to tell her for each object what to expect there.

ex. of initialization

```
 public class Lunch
    {
        public IEnumerable<Meat> Meat { get; set; } = new List<Meat>();
        public Desert Desert { get; set; } = new Desert();
        public DateTime DateTime { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
        public bool WaiterIsFriendly { get; set; } = true;
    }
```

Hope you undestand how to work with DbContext!!!

Edit:

If I have an Entity in my DbContext named Lunch, I can do the following:

```
  var lunch1=new Lunch();
Context.Lunch.Add(lunch1);
    lunch1.Desert=new Desert();
    lunch1.Meat.add(new Meat());
    
    var lunch2=new Lunch();
Context.Lunch.Add(lunch2);
    lunch2.Desert=new Desert();
    lunch2.Meat.add(new Meat());
```

and at the end I can say Context.SaveChanges();

All this can happen only if I initialize the Desert, Meat ... in Lunch class.

Comment: up for the creative example =)

Comment: I don't really know what this answer brings to the table. I understand how to utilize a DbContext. What you are failing to understand is that when I add my newly created objects into the context with AddRange, they are not available to access by my other code... the datasets are empty. Furthermore, that is just part of the problem. Even with a single SaveChanges on the context if everything else was right, the database is opening and closing connections for every single object added via AddRange. If I'm adding 200 objects, the database is opening and closing 200 times with my current code.